# Android: replacing a fragment from a button click within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I took over this android project from an outsourced developer. I do iOS development so I am still trying to get up to speed with android. The app has a top tab navigation which appears on all views. The home view is a fragment which has icons which when clicked on produce webviews that replace the home view, which the navigation tab still in view. I want to replace one of the webviews with a list view which is a fragment which I already have coded (EHallSchedFragment.java), so that when the icon is clicked on the list view replaces the home view with the navigation tab still in view. See the images below.

HOME VIEW

[image: Home View]

VIEW I WANT WHEN EXHIBIT HALL SCHEDULE ICON IS CLICKED ON

[image: New View]

Here is the code for the onClick event for that button as it exists. It calls a webView:

```
    ivExhall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                openInternalWebview("http://www.web.org/m/content.aspx?id=7006");

                //Need code here to open EhallSchedFragment.java


            }
        });
```

SO what I need is the onClick code that will open the fragment in the existing view, leaving the navigation tab in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach: Define an interface inside your fragment, implement it in your activity and then override the method there. Then finally, from your fragment, when a user clicks an item from a list, call the interface method to notify the activity of the event.

**From Your Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onClick()
{
    //when a user selects an event from your list
    switch(position)
    {
       ((OnScheduleSelectedListener) getActivity()).switchFragment(new DetailsFragment());
    }
}

public interface OnScheduleSelectedListener
{
   void switchFragment(Fragment frag);
}
```

You can then do the following in your activity:

```
public class ScheduleAppActivity extends Activity implements OnScheduleSelectedListener
{

    .............................


    @Override
    switchFragment(Fragment frag)
    {
       //check if fragment is in view here and if,
       replaceFragment(fragment)

       //else
       addFragment(frag);

       commit();
    }
}
```

So at this point, the right fragment will be added to view.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: You should add your comment above to the answer to make it more complete.

Comment: @Eenvincible I'm not sure I understand the answer. Just to clarify, the items in the list view are not clickable, it's just a static list. So do I still need to do the first code snippet since it seems that code is being used when an item in the list view is clicked? For the second code snippet is this code valid even if the Home view is a fragment and not an activity? Basically the flow is: HOME VIEW (fragment) -> ICON CLICKED ON -> LIST VIEW (fragment) APPEARS REPLACING THE HOME VIEW.

Comment: One way or the other, you MUST have an activity managing your fragments through the FragmentManager. So, just let that activity implement the interface. If the list view's items are not clickable, then you should call the notification method when an icon is clicked. So, no matter where you are (in a fragment that has other fragments), you still have an activity that manages it. If you need more help, I wouldn't mind an email chat.

Comment: Ok, I see a MainActivity which controls the navigation tabs and that seems to be managing the fragments including the Home fragment.

Comment: Yes; A fragment is managed by an activity - it cannot stand on its own. An activity is responsible for adding, removing and replacing fragments BUT only through a FragmentManager. That also means the Activity knows nothing about fragments in view.

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement and see what happens. Wrapping my head around Java is a little more challenging than I initially thought.

Comment: It is not really hard; knowing any other OOP language should make it easy to grasp it. But trust me, it is not hard at all.